# URL of the last artifact of a GitHub-action build

Tags: github-actions

I use GitHub-action for my build, and it generates multiple artifacts (with a different name).

Is there a way to predict the URL of the artifacts of the last successful build? **Without knowing the sha1**, only the name of the artifact and the repo?

Answer (score 14):

I have developed a service that exposes predictable URLs to either the latest or a particular artifact of a repository's branch+workflow.

**https://nightly.link/**
https://github.com/oprypin/nightly.link

This is implemented as a GitHub App, and communication with GitHub is authenticated, but users that only download don't need to even log in to GitHub.

---

The implementation goes and fetches this through the API, in 3 steps:

- `https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/actions/workflows/someworkflow.yml/runs?per_page=1&branch=master&event=push&status=success`
- `https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/actions/runs/123456789/artifacts?per_page=100`
- `https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/actions/artifacts/87654321/zip`

(the last one redirects you to an ephemeral direct download URL)

Note that authentication is required. For OAuth that's `public_repo` (or `repo` if appropriate). For GitHub Apps that's "Actions"/"Read-only".

---

There is indeed no more direct way to do this.

Some relevant issues are

- https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/51
- https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/27

Comment: If requiring end users to be logged in github is not a blocking issue, you may be interested in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74586595/9164010) which only relies on the URL naming scheme of artifacts (to expose these URLs as commit statuses). Otherwise, @OlehPrypin's answer is the way to go!

Answer (score 7):

At the moment, no, according to [comments from staff](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Get-artifact-URL-in-steps-after-upload-artifact/td-p/44391]) although this may change with future versions of the `upload-artifact` action.

After poking around myself, it is possible to get this using the GitHub actions API:
https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/artifacts/

> `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/actions/runs/:run_id/artifacts`

So you can receive a JSON reply and iterate through the "artifacts" array to get the corresponding "archive_download_url". A workflow can fill in the URL like so:

/repos/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id }}/artifacts

Comment: the issue is, you will need to do some process in order to filter only the last one. It's troublesome if you use something who expect some static url.

Comment: Oh, it’s a real pain - you can’t even do anything until the workflow finishes. You need to run the query in a 2nd workflow(!?) but its barely possible now.

Comment: Well, technically I need to download the artifact in another workflow repository.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command-line JSON processor along with curl to extract the URL as follows.

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/<OWNER>/<REPO_NAME>/actions/artifacts\?per_page\=<NUMBER_OF_ARTIFACTS_PER_BUILD> | jq '[.artifacts[] | {name : .name, archive_download_url : .archive_download_url}]' | jq -r '.[] | select (.name == "<NAME_OF_THE_ARTIFACT>") | .archive_download_url'
```

For example;

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/ballerina-platform/ballerina-distribution/actions/artifacts\?per_page\=9 | jq '[.artifacts[] | {name : .name, archive_download_url : .archive_download_url}]' | jq -r '.[] | select (.name == "Linux Installer deb") | .archive_download_url'
```

Here, `curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/<OWNER>/<REPO_NAME>/actions/artifacts\?per_page\=<NUMBER_OF_ARTIFACTS_PER_BUILD>` returns the array of artifacts related to the latest build.

`jq '[.artifacts[] | {name : .name, archive_download_url : .archive_download_url}]'` extracts the **artifacts** array and filters required data.

`jq -r '.[] | select (.name == "<NAME_OF_THE_ARTIFACT>") | .archive_download_url'` selects the **url** for the given artifact name.

Comment: and if you have multiple artifacts for the same name, add ' | head -n1 ' at the end :)


Many thanks for this answer

Comment: @AdiRoiban Or replace `per_page\=9` with `per_page\=1`. It should be noted that this requires artifacts to be returned sorted descending chronologically, but it does seem that this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

## Wrap-up

I recently faced with a similar use case, with the aim to **make the build artifacts of a given GitHub Actions workflow more visible**, with a single click in the commit statuses (albeit requiring users to be logged in github.com).

As pointed out by [@geoff-hutchison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131896/geoff-hutchison) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61450030/9164010):

- The API https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/artifacts/ is helpful.

However:

- It is impossible to query the list of artifacts generated by a workflow from a job of the current workflow; deferring the request [in a subsequent workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60789862/url-of-the-last-artifact-of-a-github-action-build#comment108800077_61450030) is needed.
- The `archive_download_url` URLs contained in the corresponding JSON response do not seem practical enough (they are GitHub API URLs redirecting to [ephemeral](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/50#issuecomment-580550138) URLs).

Fortunately:

- Browsing the workflow build artifacts URLs already proposed in the GitHub Actions page clearly shows that they have the form `https://github.com/${{ github.repository }}/suites/${check_suite_id}/artifacts/${artifact_id}`, and these URLs are static (*albeit only available for logged users, and for 90 days maximum, given the expiration of artifacts*).

---

## Implementation

Hence the following, generic code I developed (under MIT license) to pin all artifacts of a given workflow in commit statuses (just replace the 3 `TODO-strings`):

**.github/workflows/pin-artifacts.yml**:

```yaml
name: Pin artifacts
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows:
      - "TODO-Name Of Existing Workflow"
    types: ["completed"]
jobs:
  # Make artifacts links more visible for the upstream project
  pin-artifacts:
    permissions:
      statuses: write
    name: Add artifacts links to commit statuses
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' && github.repository == 'TODO-orga/TODO-repo' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Add artifacts links to commit status
        run: |
          set -x
          workflow_id=${{ github.event.workflow_run.workflow_id }}
          run_id=${{ github.event.workflow_run.id }}  # instead of ${{ github.run_id }}
          run_number=${{ github.event.workflow_run.run_number }}
          head_branch=${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }}
          head_sha=${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_sha }}  # instead of ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }} (or ${{ github.sha }})
          check_suite_id=${{ github.event.workflow_run.check_suite_id }}
          set +x

          curl \
          -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
          "https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${run_id}/artifacts" \
          | jq '[.artifacts | .[] | {"id": .id, "name": .name, "created_at": .created_at, "expires_at": .expires_at, "archive_download_url": .archive_download_url}] | sort_by(.name)' \
          > artifacts.json

          cat artifacts.json

          < artifacts.json jq -r ".[] | \
            .name + \"§\" + \
            ( .id | tostring | \"https://github.com/${{ github.repository }}/suites/${check_suite_id}/artifacts/\" + . ) + \"§\" + \
            ( \"Link to \" + .name + \".zip [\" + ( .created_at | sub(\"T.*\"; \"→\") ) + ( .expires_at | sub(\"T.*\"; \"] (you must be logged)\" ) ) )" \
          | while IFS="§" read name url descr; do
              curl \
              -X POST \
              -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
              -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ github.token }}" \
              "https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/statuses/${head_sha}" \
              -d "$( printf '{"state":"%s","target_url":"%s","description":"%s","context":"%s"}' "${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion }}" "$url" "$descr" "$name (artifact)" )"
          done
```

(*If need be, see also [my PR ocaml-sf/learn-ocaml#501](https://github.com/ocaml-sf/learn-ocaml/pull/501) to see an implementation example and screenshots of [this GHA workflow](https://github.com/ocaml-sf/learn-ocaml/blob/master/.github/workflows/pin-artifacts.yml).*)

Answer (score 0):

I am not a GitHub and jq guru. Probably there are more optimal solutions out there.

**jq playground link**: https://jqplay.org/s/Gm0kRcv63C - to test my solution and other possible ideas. I dropped some irrelevant field to shrink the sample JSON size (for example: *node_id, size_in_bytes, created_at...*)
Further details on the methods in the code samples below.

```
####### You can get the max date of your artifacts.
####### Then you need to choose the artifact entry by this date.
#######
####### NOTE: I just pre-formatted the first command "line".
####### 2nd "line" has a very similar, but simplified structure.
####### (at least easy to copy-paste into jq playground)

####### NOTE: ASSUMPTION:
####### First "page" of json response contains the most recent entries
#######   AND includes artifact(s) with that specific name.
#######
####### (if other artifacts flood your API response, you can increase
#######  the page size of it or do iteration on pages as a workaround)

bash$ cat artifact_response.json | \
  jq '
    (
      [
        .artifacts[]
        | select(.name == "my-artifact" and .expired == false)
        | .updated_at
      ]
      | max
    ) as $max_date
    | { $max_date }'

####### output
{ "max_date": "2021-04-29T11:22:20Z" }
```

Another way:

```
####### Latest ID of non-expired artifacts with a specific name.
####### Probably this is better solution than the above since you
####### can use the "id" instantly in your download url construction:
#######
####### "https://api.github.com/repos/blabla.../actions/artifacts/92394368/zip"
#######
####### ASSUMPTION: higher "id" means higher "update date" in your workflow
####### (there is no post-update of artifacts aka creation and
#######  update dates are identical for an artifact)


cat artifact_response.json | \
jq '[ .artifacts[] | select(.name == "my-artifact" and .expired == false) | .id ] | max'

####### output
92394368
```

More compact filter assuming in reverse order by date or id in the API response:

```
####### no full command line, just jq filter string
#######
####### no "max" function, only pick the first element by index
#######
'[ .artifacts[] | select(.name == "my-artifact" and .expired == false) | .id ][0]'
```