# How to send github action artifact in a slack notification

Tags: slack-api, github-actions

I'm trying to send customized slack notifications about the status of github action workflows. I've built my custom messages with the help of https://github.com/8398a7/action-slack integration.
However, I'm trying to send the github action artifact that is generated with each workflow to my slack channel. Is that something that can be done?

Below is the yaml file that I'm using:

```
...
env:
  SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL }}
  GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
jobs:
  smoke-test:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   container:
     image: dannydainton/htmlextra
   steps:
     - name: Cloning Repository
       id: initializing
       uses: actions/checkout@master
     - name: Executing API test suite 
       run: newman run "postman_collection.json" --environment "postman_environment.json" --reporters cli,htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-export report.html
     - if: failure()
       uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
       id: generating-report
       with:
         name: reports
         path: report.html
     - uses: 8398a7/action-slack@v3
       with:
         status: custom
         custom_payload: |
           {
              text: "Test Execution Passed",
              attachments: [{
                  color: 'good',
                  text: `Test Execution for ${process.env.AS_WORKFLOW} workflow has SUCCEEDED! :heavy_check_mark:`,
                  fields: [{
                    title: "Test Type",
                    value: 'Smoke Test',
                    short: false  
                  },
                  {
                    title: "Overall APIs Status",
                    value: "Healthy :heavy_check_mark:",
                    short: false
                  },
                  {
                    title: "Repository",
                    value: `${process.env.AS_REPO}`,
                    short: false  
                  },
                  {
                    title: "Author",
                    value: `${process.env.AS_AUTHOR}`,
                    short: false
                  },
                  {
                    title: "Execution Time",
                    value: `${process.env.AS_TOOK}`,
                    short: false
                  },
                  {
                    title: "Number of Requests",
                    value: '39',
                    short: true 
                  },
                  {
                    title: "Number of Assertions",
                    value: '64',
                    short: true    
                  }]
              }]
           }
       if: success()
     - uses: 8398a7/action-slack@v3
       if: failure()
       with:
        status: custom
        custom_payload: |
          {
            text: 'Test Execution Failed :siren_alert::siren_alert:',
            attachments: [{
                color: 'danger',
                text: `Test Execution for ${process.env.AS_WORKFLOW} workflow has FAILED! :x:`,
                fields: [{
                    title: "Test Type",
                    value: 'Smoke Test',
                    short: true
                  },
                  {
                    title: "Repository",
                    value: `${process.env.AS_REPO}`,
                    short: true
                  },
                  {
                    title: "Author",
                    value: `${process.env.AS_AUTHOR}`,
                    short: false
                  }],
                  actions: [{
                    name: "report",
                    text: "View Report",
                    type: "button",
                    value: `https://github.com/${{github.repository}}/actions/runs/${{github.run_id}}`
                  }]
              }]
          }
```

So I need to pass the artifact to the step which sends a slack notification on failure.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL of the last artifact of a GitHub-action build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60789862/url-of-the-last-artifact-of-a-github-action-build)

Comment: Thanks for the help. but that question didnt really solve my problem, in the end it generated a link for the artifact which requires people to be authorized in order to be able to download the test report. I want to make the test report available to the stakeholders, so they can be able to immediately view the report even if they dont have an access to the repo