# Any way to get a link to a GitHub action's latest result?

Tags: github, url, github-actions, github-flavored-markdown

GitHub's Actions feature recently started letting users generate badges, to showcase the status of their tests. For example, if I have a set of tests that run on my repo's dev branch from a file named `.github/test_dev.yml`, I can access that build's status by adding `/badge.svg` to the end of the test's URL.

```
https://github.com/<username>/<repo_name>/actions/workflows/test_dev.yml/badge.svg
```

That's great from the standpoint of keeping your project readme up to date with the status of the project, but the next logical step would be to also add a link to the badge that points to the latest testing outcome.

Unfortunately, even though you can access all the tests of a particular action as follows:

```
https://github.com/<username>/<repo_name>/actions/workflows/test_dev.yml
```

The test runs themselves seem to be behind a unique ID under `actions/runs/`.

```
https://github.com/<username>/<repo_name>/actions/runs/1234567890
```

Is there any way to construct a URL that just points to the latest test? Something like:

```
https://github.com/<username>/<repo_name>/actions/workflows/test_dev.yml?result=latest
```

I poked through GitHub's documentation, but even though there's some documentation surrounding the generation of those badge SVG's, I couldn't find anything about linking directly to the action that actually generated that SVG.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have a similar problem (want to obtain a link to latest created artifacts)...

Comment: Ha, artifact links can be obtained with a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65163515/599884

Answer (score 2):

you can use this to get the id in a yaml file:

`https://github.com/<username>/<repo_name>/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id }}`